# MongoDB + .NET Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

so I'm working on an app backend with .NET Core 1.0 and have a bunch of the work already put in. I guess it's my own fault for not checking beforehand, but apparently the latest version of MongoDB's C# driver (2.2.4) is not compatible with .NET Core 1.0?

I get errors like these for all the relevant dependencies:

```
The dependency MongoDB.Bson 2.2.4 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

I came across this guide on how to get it working with RC2 but we're a bit past that point now (I'd be reluctant to use a release candidate version for a real project like this): http://blog.stoverud.no/posts/referencing-net451-libraries-in-aspnet-core/

The above guide isn't working for me. Adding the framework under "frameworks" in the project JSON file just creates another unsupported error similar to the one above.

Is there a way to get this done or should I be looking at another database? I don't know too many database projects. I need to use NoSQL.

Comment: dnx452 is equal  to net452 (just w/o dnx runtime) moniker, so you can still use the net452 moniker to build your appliation, but you'll need the full .NET 4.5.2 Framework installed (or target mono for well linux/macos). It was never possible to run MongoDB with .NET Core though, as it's not compatible with it yet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

The version 2.3.0 has been officially released and it is compatible with .NET Core 1.0, so I guess this question is no longer relevant.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.3.0

---

**Old answer:**

The version 2.3.0 is currently in beta and I was able to add it to my .net core app, I haven't done much work with it so I don't know the current limitations/bugs.

Add to your project.json file the dependency:

```
 "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.3.0-beta1"
```

Or use the ***Include prerelease*** checkbox in the NuGet manager and search for the **MongoDB.Driver.Core** package.

According to this page, it seems they are close to finish it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1177

Comment: I ended up using node.js instead *cringe*

Comment: I checked today, and 2.3.0-rc1 is available. see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.3.0-rc1

Comment: @CVertex Thanks, I'll consider it if I ever decide to jump off a bridge for having to use node

Comment: Its worth noting that the driver also runs with .Net Core 2.0 - although I cant find a specific reference to back that up, I'm running Driver 2.4.4 in a Core 2 project.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB add support for .net core in their private nuget feed.
This is pre release feed but could help.

https://www.myget.org/gallery/mongodb